# I turned my thermostat off on my furnace and my furnace is still blowing cold air

Tags: furnace

I turn off my thermostat on my furnace and my furnace is still blowing. And it is blowing cold air.

Comment: There should be a switch to turn off the furnace off completely and/or use the circuit breaker.  There seems something not right with the fan.  Maybe it is just set to be on all the time,instead of auto, or the temperature sensor is not turning it off after cool down.

Comment: Does your thermostat have an option to keep the blower on with the heat off?

Answer (score 4):

First if your house has built-in A/C, your thermostat certainly has a switch for the fan, which has 2 positions: "ON" and "AUTO".  In "ON" it will run the fan continuously.

By the way, that's because a forced-air furnace does not know the house is equipped with air conditioning.  The A/C needs the furnace's air handler to push the cold air around, so the thermostat has to separately ask the A/C to run and also ask the furnace to run fan-only.  Since it's there, they give you a switch to control it yourself. Some people use it on programmable thermostats to run a "fan schedule", just to stir the air in the house e.g. to get air to a dehumidifier.

If you didn't throw that "fan switch", and you don't have a "fan schedule" programmed, then you may have a malfunctioning thermostat or furnace.

The wiring to the thermostat is 24 volts AC - perfectly harmless if you don't, like, *lick it*... and you can get an AC voltmeter and check voltages.   Remember to set your multimeter on AC.

"R" is the common wire.

"G" is the fan wire.  When the thermostat is "calling for fan", there will be less than 1 volt between R and G.  When the thermostat is *not* calling for fan, the voltage between them should be *roughly* 24 volts AC.  18-30 volts would be fine.

"W" is the "call for heat".  When the thermostat calls for heat, the fan runs automatically under the furnace's control, *regardless of what's happening on the G wire*.

Most furnaces have a thermal sensor on their gas/air heat exchanger.  You typically hear "fa-woosh" of the gas burner starting, then 30 seconds laster after the heat exchanger has warmed up, "ssssshhhhh" as the fan starts up (so it's not blowing cold air for the first 30 seconds).    The reverse happens on shutdown; the gas shuts off *but the heat exchanger is still hot* so it keeps running the fan for a minute more so that heat isn't wasted.  The fan shuts off when it cools off.

If this sensor malfunctions, the fan might stick "on".

Answer (score 0):

Do not know how you turned the thermostat off,

but check if the Fan function is engaged on the thermostat

If noting else works pull the G wire on the thermostat.

Comment: could be a timer that runs the fan for fresh air intake.  check to see if you have a timer on the furnace and what the time of day it's set to run.